# Android data loading as in Drop Down list Manner

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

Is there any way to show data (approx:50 at a time) from my database in an drop down list manner?

Answer (score 1):

[Spinner](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) provides look and feel of drop-down try using this.